# Import a single configuration, producing errors - The configuration cannot be imported because it failed validation for the following reasons

Tags: 8, configuration, importing-exporting

Drupal 8.9.9

The configuration import for a single item import is not working. (I'm trying this on the same system to rule out any configuration mismatches between environments)

Steps

1. Create a simple view
2. Generate the single item export
3. Delete the view created in step 1
4. Import the configuraition created in step 2.

```
uuid: xxx
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  config:
    - core.entity_view_mode.node.teaser
    - node.type.club_route
  module:
    - node
    - user
id: test_view
label: 'Test View'
module: views
description: ''
tag: ''
base_table: node_field_data
base_field: nid
display:
  default:
    display_plugin: default
    id: default
    display_title: Master
    position: 0
    display_options:
      access:
        type: perm
        options:
          perm: 'access content'
      cache:
        type: tag
        options: {  }
      query:
        type: views_query
        options:
          disable_sql_rewrite: false
          distinct: false
          replica: false
          query_comment: ''
          query_tags: {  }
      exposed_form:
        type: basic
        options:
          submit_button: Apply
          reset_button: false
          reset_button_label: Reset
          exposed_sorts_label: 'Sort by'
          expose_sort_order: true
          sort_asc_label: Asc
          sort_desc_label: Desc
      pager:
        type: some
        options:
          items_per_page: 10
          offset: 0
      style:
        type: html_list
      row:
        type: 'entity:node'
        options:
          view_mode: teaser
      fields:
        title:
          id: title
          table: node_field_data
          field: title
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: title
          label: ''
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            make_link: false
            absolute: false
            trim: false
            word_boundary: false
            ellipsis: false
            strip_tags: false
            html: false
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          settings:
            link_to_entity: true
          plugin_id: field
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          exclude: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: true
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: value
          type: string
          group_column: value
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
      filters:
        status:
          value: '1'
          table: node_field_data
          field: status
          plugin_id: boolean
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: status
          id: status
          expose:
            operator: ''
            operator_limit_selection: false
            operator_list: {  }
          group: 1
        type:
          id: type
          table: node_field_data
          field: type
          value:
            club_route: club_route
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: type
          plugin_id: bundle
          expose:
            operator_limit_selection: false
            operator_list: {  }
      sorts:
        created:
          id: created
          table: node_field_data
          field: created
          order: DESC
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: created
          plugin_id: date
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          exposed: false
          expose:
            label: ''
          granularity: second
      title: 'Test View'
      header: {  }
      footer: {  }
      empty: {  }
      relationships: {  }
      arguments: {  }
      display_extenders: {  }
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: -1
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - 'user.node_grants:view'
        - user.permissions
      tags: {  }
  page_1:
    display_plugin: page
    id: page_1
    display_title: Page
    position: 1
    display_options:
      display_extenders: {  }
      path: test-view
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: -1
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - 'user.node_grants:view'
        - user.permissions
      tags: {  }
```

Error message:

```
The configuration cannot be imported because it failed validation for the following reasons:
Configuration block.block.bootstrap_comment_recent depends on the bootstrap theme that will not be installed after import.
Configuration block.block.bootstrap_search_form depends on the bootstrap theme that will not be installed after import.
Configuration block.block.bootstrap_system_main depends on the bootstrap theme that will not be installed after import.
Configuration block.block.bootstrap_user_new depends on the bootstrap theme that will not be installed after import.
Configuration block.block.bootstrap_user_online depends on the bootstrap theme that will not be installed after import.
Configuration block.block.color_glass_system_main depends on the color_glass theme that will not be installed after import.
Configuration block.block.eerrbootstrap_system_main depends on the eerrbootstrap theme that will not be installed after import.
Configuration block.block.eerr_system_main depends on the eerr theme that will not be installed after import.
Configuration block.block.multipurpose_zymphonies_theme_system_main depends on the multipurpose_zymphonies_theme theme that will not be installed after import.
Configuration block.block.tweme_system_main depends on the tweme theme that will not be installed after import.
Configuration bootstrap.settings depends on the bootstrap extension that will not be installed after import.
Configuration eerr2016.settings depends on the eerr2016 extension that will not be installed after import.
Configuration language.types depends on the Language module that will not be installed after import.
Configuration tweme.settings depends on the tweme extension that will not be installed after import.
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: did you clear cache after deleting the View ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on [Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap/issues/2706711):

To deal with this issue:

What I did in source website:
run `drush cex`
in config repository, remove [non-existent theme].settings.yml
run `drush cim`
run `drush cex` // to confirm export is clean
deliver config files in target website
What I did in target website
run `drush cim` // or import all in synchronisation interface
Now config import is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the post: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3144341

Deleting those configurations fix the issue.

```
drush config-delete "your-config-name"
```